# Alternative industry lingo expression for "close the deal"?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

Famous Alec Baldwin movie had the quote

> Coffee is for closers

Here closer refers to closing the (sales)deal.

What other "sales" industry phrase can I use, instead of this.

I can think of a few such as converting a lead, make a sale, seal the deal.

Could somebody recommend me a few more?

Answer (score 1):

We could consider **clinch a/the deal** where [clinch](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/clinch) means

> to finally get or win something:
> I hear he finally clinched the deal to buy the land he wanted.

**secure a/the deal** is also possible.

[ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=clinch+a+deal%2Cclinch+the+deal%2Csecure+a+deal%2Csecure+the+deal&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cclinch%20a%20deal%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cclinch%20the%20deal%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csecure%20a%20deal%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csecure%20the%20deal%3B%2Cc0) shows that these are used.

Comment: Also seal the deal, finalise the deal.